# Subdivision Surface modifier not working if applied

Tags: rendering

Well, I started making a plate for my pie. I added an subdivision modifier, when I do not apply it, in the render it shows in the level I set. If I apply it, in the render it shows subdivision on level 1. I don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: When you apply a subsurf modifier, it uses the number of levels in the Viewport box, not the Render value, so make sure the first one is set to the number of subdivisions you want.

Comment: Thank You! Just noticed that, I'm dum

Comment: Hi and Welcome! Do you mind adding an *answer*? This is no forum rather a Q&A site, meaning a knowledge base. In order to help future visitors, please do not add [ANSWERED] to the question title, add an answer instead. Thanks. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @brockmann you could answer as well by now to get this off the unanswered list. OP may or may not be back to this Q.

Comment: Yeah of course, main concern was to provide a few hints to the OP on how this site works @Timaroberts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply a subsurf modifier, it uses the number of levels in the Viewport box, not the Render value, so make sure the first one is set to the number of subdivisions you want.